# What's the meaning of "flatlands of paper"

Tags: meaning

In the following paragraph, Edward Tufte speaks of "flatlands of paper."
I don't understand its meaning:

> Even though we navigate daily through a perceptual world of three
>   dimensions and reason occasionally about higher dimensional arena with
>   mathematical ease, the world portrayed on our information displays is
>   caught up in the two-dimensionality of the **flatlands of paper** and
>   video screen

Answer (score 19):

It is a reference to  Edwin Abbott's classic satirical novella [*Flatland*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatland).  Tufte is saying although we live a real, three-dimensional world, we get most of our information in artificial, two-dimensional representations: paper and on-screen.

Comment: I don't remember whether he credits Abbott, but Carl Sagan also made this term famous in an episode (#10) of the original [Cosmos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmos:_A_Personal_Voyage).  The flatlander's (2D people) encounter w/ 3D objects is used to parallel a 3D person's possible perspective on 4D space.

Comment: @goldilocks, "[Let's imagine that we are perfectly flat](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=cosmos-carl-sagan&episode=s01e10). I mean, absolutely flat and that we live, appropriately enough, in Flatland a land designed and named by Edwin Abbott, a Shakespearean scholar who lived in Victorian England."  So, yes, although describing Abbott as a "Shakespearean scholar" seems as reductive as describing a man who survived until 1926 as "living in Victorian England" (The good Queen herself died in 1901.)

Comment: @goldilocks, but Sagan may have had in mind Hal Clement's S-F classic *Mission of Gravity*, where we encounter natives of a Jovian planet who live in an almost 2 dimensional world because the high gravity allows little movement in the 3rd dimension.

Answer (score 3):

> ["flatland"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flatland) - a region in which the land is predominantly flat —usually used in plural

"flatlands of paper" - **a metaphor for books, newspapers and written information in general.**

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: It's not my downvote, but it's probably because your answer is wrong -- it is, as Malvolio suggests, a reference to Abbott's book.

Comment: @Charles - evidence? Other than Malvolio's assertion? For that matter, even if it's a reference to *Flatland*, "flatland" itself is a more general term and someone could understand the metaphor without any knowledge of Abbott's (or Tufte's) work.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy: It's pretty evident from the original quote, if you've read the book. But I don't feel obliged to defend someone else's downvote, I was just explaining. Apparently the 16 people who voted for Malvolio's answer felt similarly.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy, describing paper or video display as "flatlands" in the sense of prairie doesn't make a lot of sense on its own: a 24"-inch monitor is not useful for raising cattle or wheat; sheets of paper aren't good farmland.  Throw in references to dimensionality and mathematics, and I am pretty confident we are talking about the book.

Comment: @Charles, This is a good answer and a useful addition to Malvolio's sparse answer.  Afterall, the book title referenced has a context that is both literal and figuative with many rich associations. Since I come from the flatlands of my country, I am quite aware of the way  this term can be used derisively of a place (& its flatlander inhabitants) to mean dull and lifeless, i.e. flat in the figurative sense.